# Matplotlib erase figure and plot new series of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a series of figures with 3x3 subplots using matplotlib. I can make the first figure fine (9 total subplots), but when I try to make a tenth subplot I get this error: ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 9, not 10. What I think I want to do is plot the first 9 subplots, clear the figure, and then plot the next 9 subplots. I haven't been able to get this approach to work so far though. If anyone could offer some suggestions I would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: Add in your question the code which you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Call `plt.show()` before the 10th chart, then start over with `plt.subplot(3, 3, 1)`, followed by the code to plot the 10th chart

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a new figure after plotting each subplot of the first figure.

for ex-

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,3)
plt.figure(2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,3)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]